# What’s the command prompt to update Ubuntu 20.04 6 LTS

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I’m working with Windows 11 Pro in a virtual environment in the windows subsystem for Linux using Ubuntu 20.04 6 LST, all the command I have tried had not worked.

To update my Linux shell for bash. It keep giving me:

> -bash syntax error near unexpected token or usr/bin/script: cannot execute binary file.

Help please if you can.

Comment: Which is which (VM , Host) .  Ubuntu updates via Live Patch. Is that enabled?  Also perhaps try Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Did you by any chance edit a Linux file by use of Windows utility? Then you may have created CR+LF line endings.Linux uses LF only, and certain tools may get confused  if it finds something else.

Answer (score 0):

The process is described in the article
[How to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-22-04-lts/).

Here is a summary of the process :

- Ensure the default behavior of the release upgrader.
  Check if the file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` contains
  the line `Prompt=lts`
- Unhold all held packages :

  - Verify if packages are held : `sudo apt-mark showhold`
  - Unhold packages : `sudo apt-mark unhold pkg1 pkg2`
- Update current system :

  ```
  sudo apt update #<--Refresh the apt repo
  sudo apt upgrade #<--Now apply all upgrades
  ```
- Reboot : `sudo reboot`
- Note down the Linux distro name and kernel version :

  ```
  uname -mrs
  lsb_release -a
  ```
- Open TCP port 1022 :

  ```
  sudo ufw allow 1022/tcp comment 'Open port ssh tcp port 1022 as failsafe option for upgrades'
  ```

  Verify it:

  ```
  sudo ufw status
  ```
- Upgrade : `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

More details with screenshots can be found in the above article.